# why we use cauchy sequence to define a complete metric space, but not other way?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that using cauchy sequence to define a complete metric space allows us "extend" the properties of real line to other space, but is there any other way preserve the properties of real line(like least upper bound axiom, order axiom) in other space?

Comment: Very few metric spaces admit an ordering where the open balls in the metric are exactly the open intervals in the ordering. So sup and order axioms are no good in general.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Did mathematicians propose other theories to solve this problem? And is the definition complete space "unique", could we use other approach to define the same thing or sth similarly?

Comment: what metric spaces admit  ordering axiom?

Comment: It took almost 24 centuries to come up with a suitable definition of a real number after realizing the need for irrationality. It was Georg Cantor who outlined how to define a real number as an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences. After that, the construction became standard; because the same construction worked for normed spaces, there was little need to attempt anything else in such cases. What would be gained by assuming more structure in order to obtain a completion, especially knowing that the norm completion is unique up to isometric isomorphism?

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you for your comment. I don't understand your question well. If we assume more , we could get some limit points in the original space. Then a space including the original one and those limit points is the completion of the original one. But I am not quite familiar with the "unique" completion, my understanding is that we can have 2 completions of the original one, but they are the same in the sense of metric space, like same cardinality and their metric is the same after projection of some function f

Comment: @JoeHo : If $X$ is a normed space, then there exists a complete normed space $\tilde{X}$ such that $X$ is densely and isometrically contained in $\tilde{X}$. If there are two such completions, then the completions are isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: @TrialAndError : Thank you for your explanation for "unique" completion, but I still don't understand your question "What would be gained by assuming more structure in order to obtain a completion, especially knowing that the norm completion is unique up to isometric isomorphism?". Do you mean we can get something else other than completed space after we add some limit points into the original space?

Comment: @JoeHo : If your goal is to find the completion, then it makes no sense to add extra assumptions; you're going to find the same completion with or without the extra assumptions.

Comment: @TrialAndError : Certainly, this is done if we just want to find the completion, and by completion theorem(which doesn't have extra assumptions), we don't need to find another completion, as they are the same up to to isometric isomorphism.

Comment: @JoeHo : Adding assumptions is not going to lead to a larger completion, right? And there is no smaller completion; the construction using Cauchy sequences is the smallest. So ...